# Yii2 rule not being applied

Tags: php, yii2

This is for a variable that isn't in my DB. But used to update my password.
I declare it as `public $newPassword;` at the start of my User class.
In my class I have the following rules:

```
public function rules()
  {
    return [
        ...
        [['email'], 'string', 'max' => 150],
        [['email'], 'email'],
        [['password', 'newPassword'], 'string', 'length' => [6,20]],
        [['password', 'newPassword'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^(?=[^\d_].*?\d)\w(\w|[!@#$%]){5,20}/', 'message' => 'Must start with a letter, contain at least 1 digit, available special chars are: !@#$%'],

    ];
}
```

scenarios

```
public function scenarios() 
{
    return [
        self::SCENARIO_PASSWORD => ['newPassword', 'password'],
        ...
    ];
}
```

The scenario works fine and so does the regex. But I can leave my new password blank and it passes validation and I really don't know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add separate `required` rule for both current and new passwords so user can't leave them blank:

```
[['password', 'newPassword'], 'required'],
```

**Official docs:**

- [Validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html)
- [RequiredValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-requiredvalidator.html)